# When should I use .copy()

Tags: python, numpy

I know that for the following:

```
a=1
b=a
a=4
```

It assigns `1` to `a` and then `a` to `b` followed by changing the value of `a` to `4` as the last step.
Here once the value of `a` is changed to `4`, there will not be any changes to the value of `b`.

Similarly  for

```
a=np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60])
b=a[2]

a[2]=100
```

the value of `b` at the end of the code will be `20` which was the initial `a[2]`.

But when you have some thing as given bellow:

```
a=np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60])
b=a[0:2]
```

and if we change `a[0:2]=[100,200]` then the value of `b` will also change automatically. It is like the variable `b` is linked somehow other ( which was different to the previous cases).
And I do know that if the code is written as `b=a[0:2].copy()` then the `b` will not change even though `a` is changed.

So my question is where exactly should I be using this `.copy()` method if I don't want to change the latter variable because it wasn't necessary in the first two cases

Appreciate your help

Comment: Is your question specific to `numpy` (which has non-standard slicing mechanisms), or about Python in general (where slicing is almost always a shallow copy, the sole exception to this in the built-ins that I know of being the `memoryview` type). I'm assuming the former (the behavior that confuses you is largely unique to `numpy` and packages based on it), but `.copy()` is a method on so many types it's not clear. I'll note: The rules will always depend on the types involved; slicing has no *guaranteed* behaviors, so you need to know what the rules are for that type.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you for the response. So if we focus on  `numpy`... 
Here in my second example, which is a numpy array,  it doesn't effect the variable `b`. 

But in the third case, it does. So can you suggest an appropriate way to identify whether the variables are linked or not..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first & second cases, you have assigned a single value (scalar) to `b`.

In the third case, you've assigned a [view](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html#term-view) based on the slice `0:2` of `a` to `b` (see [basic-slicing-and-indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing)). That is essentially a multivalued reference to certain elements of `a` (i.e.: `b[0]` really refers to `a[0]`). In other words, `b` does not own its data, but *points* to data in `a`. Thus, when changing `a`, `b` just reflects those changes because it points to the very same  elements.

In general, you should use numpy `copy()` when you want to dissociate the copy from the original, for instance:

1. when you are about to make modifications to the copy (not cool to sneakily mutate the caller's data, for example),
2. when you want to keep a snapshot of the array at that point, no matter what happens to the original later,
3. when you have very sparse slicing or in a random order, and you want to get a more compact copy for faster operations (locality of reference),
4. when you'd like to change the flags of `a` or `b` (e.g. from C-continuous to F-continuous, again usually for speed reasons).

With regard to your question in comments "is there any way to to identify whether the variables are linked or not": yes. Each numpy array has `flags`:

```
a=np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60])
b=a[2]
b.flags.owndata
# True  -- funny given that b is a single numpy.int64, but it still has flags

b=a[0:2]
b.flags.owndata
# False

a=np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60])
b=a[0:2].copy()
b.flags.owndata
# True
```

Comment: This is wrong "`b`, being a shallow copy, is affected as well." `b` is not a shallow copy; if it were, reassigning the top-level items in it or `a` (and it only has top-level items, being a 1D array) would not change the other. `b` is a *view* of a portion of `a`, in much the same way `somedict.items()` is (on Python 3) a view of the underlying `dict` (so changing the `dict` changes the items view).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, then it's not a slice but a view (I even checked that documentation there, it never calls the result of slicing a slice).

Comment: @ShadowRanger and @superbrain you are both right about it being a view. That is the actual name of the object. The [slice](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#slice) is the range itself, in this case `0:2`. Naming aside, the whole point is that, if I'm not mistaken, the [view](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html#term-view) simply contains pointers (references) to the values in `a`.

Comment: @PierreD: Yes, my objection was specifically to the term "shallow copy" (since no actual copying was occurring). Post edit, the wording is correct; up-voted (and deleted my own answer, since your edits added the additional info that was missing and justified my own answer).